# Docker-compose not attaching redis: redis does not start

Tags: redis, docker, docker-compose

I have an issue with my docker-compose configuration that I cannot pinpoint: redis won't start.

My **docker-compose.yml**:

```
web:
  build: ./web
  links:
   - db
   - redis
  ports:
   - "8080:8080"
db:
  image: mysql
  ports:
    - "3307:3306"
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    MYSQL_DATABASE: bignibou_dev
redis:
  build: ./redis
  ports:
    - "63790:6379"
```

My **./web/Dockerfile**:

```
FROM java:8
ADD ./bignibou-server-1.0.jar /app/bignibou-server-1.0.jar
ADD ./spring-cloud.properties /app/spring-cloud.properties
ENV SPRING_CLOUD_PROPERTIESFILE=/app/spring-cloud.properties
ENV SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=cloud
ENV SPRING_CLOUD_APP_NAME=bignibou
ENV CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:root@localhost:3307/bignibou_dev
ENV REDISCLOUD_URL=redis://dummy:dummy@localhost:63790
ENV DYNO=dummy
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT [ "java", "-jar", "/app/bignibou-server-1.0.jar" ]
```

My **./redis/Dockerfile**:

```
FROM redis
COPY redis.conf /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
EXPOSE 6379
ENTRYPOINT [ "redis-server", "/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf" ]
```

When I run `sudo docker-compose up`, **redis** is not started by Docker although **mysql/db** starts properly.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: I hope that's not a real API key...

Comment: What debugging have you done? Can you try running in the background with `docker-compose -d` and checking if the container gets created with `docker ps -a`? If the container does indeed get created, can you share the logs with `docker logs <container_id>`?

Comment: Hi Andy, It seems there is no such option as `-d` for `docker-compose`. The container does get created though. `docker logs container_id` is empty (no output)...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of localhost  , write your redis service name which in your case is redis , so connection will be like :

```
   redis://dummy:dummy@redis:63790
```